# When two people get the same amount of kills, how is the round MVP rewarded in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In CS:GO there are a couple of rules I know for awarding MVP, such as a bomb plant and 1 kill giving an MVP over 2 kills, etc.

But when 2 players get the same amount of kills, how is the MVP rewarded? Is it based off the amount of damage?